# One class function works but another doesnt

Tags: flutter, class, dart

i tride to implement a new method in my class but couldn't get any output from it, tried with a test method and it still doesn't output anything.

Below is the class:

```
class StockFileManager {
  String _file;

  StockFileManager({required String file}) : _file = file;

  set file(String file) => _file = file;


  // Made this test to see why new function isn't working.

  String test() { 
    String test = 'Testar';
    print(test);
    return test;
  }



  List getFileAsListOfLists() {
    // reading the passed file to 1 (!) string in a list
    print('enter');
    List<String> lines = File(_file).readAsLinesSync();

    List values = [];

    for (var line in lines) {
      values.add(line.split(','));
    }
    return values;
  }
}
```

This is the code that is using the class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:invmgr/data_management/file_mgr.dart';
import 'add_stock_screen.dart';

//needed variables
var wareHouse = StockFileManager(file: '../assets/xyz.csv');

List stockList = wareHouse.getFileAsListOfLists(); // this works
String test = wareHouse.test(); // this doesn't work??



  //Flutter code below
```

edit:

Now i tried to do breakpoints in the code.
After declaring stockList (calling warehouse.getFileAsListOfLists(), console prints "Enter"
It then skips my breakpoint at String test = wareHouse.test().
goes to the flutter construction.

However, If i call the variable test with a flutter button later when it's up and running, THEN it goes to that row and gets the value 'testar'.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is the expected behavior, and what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: So you are saying, if you do `String test = wareHouse.test()` your code doesn't throw any error, but neither does it print `Testar` nor does the `test` variable have the value `Testar`? This seems quite hard to believe. So forgive me if I ask a dumb question: Are you sure you are running the correct files and everything is properly saved before you are running it?

Comment: Yes depircher, that is correct. i have tried this.

Now i tried to do breakpoints in the code and after declaring stockList (calling warehouse.getFileAsListOfLists(), console prints "Enter" it then skips my breakpoint at String test = wareHouse.test() and goes to the flutter construction.

However,
If i call the variable test with a flutter button when it's up and running, THEN it goes to that row and gets the value 'testar'.

Comment: maybe there is an exception here : List stockList = wareHouse.getFileAsListOfLists(); // this works ,  use try catch to capture the error

Comment: Im sorry i'm pretty new to Dart, how would i go about implementing that?

Comment: try {
List stockList = wareHouse.getFileAsListOfLists(); // this works

} catch(e){  print(e);} 

String test = wareHouse.test(); // this doesn't work??

Comment: Please post a [mcve], otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: update: 
I couldnt use try since it's in the beggining of the class where i can only declare variables, try needed to be inside {}

it works when I put both lines in my widget build(buildcontext context){} method, and not in the beginning.

BUT I removed it from there because the methods will be called every time I use setState().

Any input?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code from your example, I could find nothing wrong, and the Test method works as expected. Please note that I have had to add a mock for the File(_file).readAsLinesSync().

```
    void main() {
  // variables
  var wareHouse = StockFileManager(file: '../assets/xyz.csv');

  // test of warehouse stock holdings
  List stockList = wareHouse.getFileAsListOfLists();
  for (var element in stockList) {
    print(element);
  } 
  String test = wareHouse.test(); // this does work.
}

class StockFileManager {
  String _file;

  StockFileManager({required String file}) : _file = file;

  set file(String file) => _file = file;

  String test() {
    String test = 'Testar is working';
    print(test);
    return test;
  }

  List getFileAsListOfLists() {
    print('enter');
    List<String> lines = ['Hello', 'World', '!', '!', '!'];

    List values = [];

    for (var line in lines) {
      values.add(line.split(','));
    }
    return values;
  }
}
```

[image]

What is the problem that you are experiencing?